# How to pass parameter mvc via jquery GET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to pass a value to a Url.Action like so

```
     $('._select_change').change(function(n)
     {
         var param = n.target.value;

         $.get('@Url.Action("List", new { someid = param } )', function (data) {
             $('#changeArea').replaceWith(data);
         });

     });
```

if i set someid = '123', then the value carries through fine. However when I replace with someid = param - i get a compiler error "CS0103: The name 'param' does not exist in the current context"  ...

how should i structure this method call?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how should i structure this method call?

Like this:

```
$('._select_change').change(function() {
    var param = $(this).val();
    $.get('@Url.Action("List")', { someid: param }, function (data) {
         $('#changeArea').replaceWith(data);
    });
});
```

Notice how I am using the second argument of the `$.get()` method to pass query string arguments to the AJAX call from the client.

This would pass the selected value of a dropdown to the List controller action taking a `someid` action argument:

```
public ActionResult List(string someid) 
{
    ...
}
```

So what you will see in the Net tab of your javascript debugging tool is the following AJAX request being sent to the server:

```
GET /somecontroller/List?someid=123
```

There's one thing though that you should be careful with if you use this `$.get()` method. GET requests are usually cached by browsers. This means that if you send many requests to the same url like `/list?someid=123` the browser could cache the result and only the first request will ever reach the server. But what if you want to server *fresh* data every time and you want to hit the server for each request. The recommended solution in this case is to use the `$.ajax()` method instead which allows you to disable the cache:

```
$('._select_change').change(function() {
    var param = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("List")',
        data: { someid: param },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { 
            $('#changeArea').replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This will append a random query string parameter on each request to ensure that the result is not cached by the client browser.

Comment: once again DD to the rescue, I should probably kickback some of my salary to you ;)

Comment: It's always a pleasure when I can help a peer developer in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            url: YourURL,
            type: "post",
           data: $('form').serialize(), // one way of submitting full form
           data: { id: "your ID", name: "your name" }, // if you have less parameters use this 
            success: function (data) {
                // handle it

            },
            error: function (data) {
                // handle your error
            },
            dataType: "JSON"
            //async:true
        });
```